# Is it possible to get a stack overflow while using quicksort in average running time?

Tags: c

I know that this sounds stupid, but if we assume that we are lucky and get an average time complexity of O(NlogN) every single time for quick sort, then regardless of the size of the array we will never get a segmentation fault because even though we are making countless recursive calls and we are allocating space to the call stack, we never really use up the entire call stack reserved memory because we are breaking it down in logn time and combing it in linear time.

Of course this is my thoughts on a take home question my professor left us to think about when we were on segmentation faults in our class. Am I wrong in thinking that a segmentation fault never occurs if we assume it to always have an average running time complexity?

**Here is the Question:**

If we had a computer system with a heap of 2GB and that the size of the call stack for an application is 1MB. And assume that each recursive call to quicksort requires 256 bytes to be allocated to the call stack. Is it possible to get a stack overflow?

EDIT:

This is assuming that our algorithm will run in average time complexity, with the computer specifications noted in the question. Sorry for not being specific enough.

EDIT2:

Our input size will be equal to or less than 2gb,which is our heap size.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  If it's simply "does log(N) ever exceed the stack size?", then it depends on N and the stack size.

Comment: The call stack was told to be 1mb by my professor, I guess my logic was flawed? Since my prof did mention that we should assume an average running time for this quick sort.

Comment: Be clear what kind of Big-O you have: Lower, upper, average, tight. For quicksort, O(n log n) is average. And for quicksort if you assume you have use average time, you will use average space too.

Comment: Consider that the whole heap is full and you're trying to sort it. How many recursive calls would that take? Then you can easily see if you run the danger of a stack overflow or not.

Comment: @Deduplicator: You mean "best/worst", not "lower/upper", right?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific yet again, if the last puzzle to solving this question is the size of inputs, then lets say our input is within the range of the space given to us by the heap. So it never crosses the 2gb mark.

Comment: The key point is the *number of items*, not the total size of the input.  If your 2GB input consists of 1 2GB-sized record, there will be 0 recursive calls!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot calculate this without having the number of elements you are considering for your input. Stack overflow error in this case would be a function of "number of elements" and "stack size". Out of these you are missing one.

Comment: If our input size was less than or equal to 2gb (our heap size) would my statement hold?

Answer (score 0):

Programs using recursive approach are most likely to get to a stack overflow when the input is relatively huge. On the other hand, iterative approach is much performant and safe. As stated above the answer to your question depends on how huge your input is. But, to get an idea about how fast a recursive program can damage a stack comparing to an iterative program, you may take a look at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21194/Iterative-vs-Recursive-Approaches

Just as a general advice, it is not a good idea to use recursive in critical sections of your program.